# How to access dynamic key of an object?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I want to access the value of `record.year` but I want it to be done dynamically.
From my understanding, I could also do record["year"] to get the same value.

In this case, I want my chart to dynamically accept different x-y axis, hence I'm using `fields[0]` which returns the string of the key. `fields[0] = "year";` in this case, but I am getting an error.

The following is my code, Line 3 doesn't give an error while Line 2 does.

```
data: records.map(record => { 
          // return { x: record[fields[0]], y: record.employment_rate_overall }  //fields[0] = "year";
          return { x: record["year"], y: record.employment_rate_overall }
        })
```

The error is `No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type {object}`.
I have confirmed that fields[0] is a string.

I have tried `someObj[field as keyof ObjectType]` as well as `someObj[field as keyof typeof someObj]` and it didn't work.

EDIT:

```
type records: {
      basic_monthly_mean: string,
      basic_monthly_median: string,
      degree: string,
      employment_rate_ft_perm: string,
      employment_rate_overall: string,
      gross_monthly_mean: string,
      gross_monthly_median: string,
      gross_mthly_25_percentile: string,
      gross_mthly_75_percentile: string,
      school: string,
      university: string,
      year: string,
      _id: number
    }[];
```

```
var fields: string[] = [];
fields.push("year");

const data = {
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'Employment Rate Overall',
        data: records.map(record => { 
          return { x: record[fields[0]], y: record.employment_rate_overall }
        }),
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
      }
    ],
  };
```

Comment: `fields[0]` could be anything, so there's no guarantee the property exists on a type like `{year: number}`. There's a difference between the key being any `string` and a key being one of a couple of well-defined literals as `"year"`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please consider providing a [mre] someone could paste into a standalone IDE to see the issue you're seeing.  Right now my IDE would just complain that `records` isn't defined, so I don't have much insight into what's going on.

Comment: @NotX Thanks for clarifying it, I understand the issue now. Is there a way such that `fields[0]` can be recognized as `"year"`? Or are there any alternative suggestions?

Comment: @jcalz I have added the structure of `records`, hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could do something like

```js
const fields = ['basic_monthly_mean', 'year'] as const; // and all the other fields
type Record = {[k in typeof fields[number]]: string};
type Records = Record[];
```

The disadvantage: `_id` of type `number` wouldn't fit in here, so you might have to wrap `Record` like

```js
type RecordWithId = {
  _id: number
  record: Record
}
```

and `type Records = RecordWithId[];`